# Installing a package from private GitLab server on Windows

Tags: r, windows, gitlab, devtools

I am struggling with installing a package from a GitLab repository on a Windows computer.

I found different hints but still have problems to install my package from GitLab. First of all, I generated a public and private key with puttygen.exe. The files need to be changed afterwards, I had to remove comments and stuff so they look like my the file on my Unix system. So now, both public and private key files have just a single line.

I tried to install my package via `devtools::install_git` which takes very long and I get the error message

```
Error: Failed to install 'unknown package' from Git:
  Error in 'git2r_remote_ls': Failed to authenticate SSH session: Unable to send userauth-publickey request
```

And with `devtools::install_gitlab` I get a different error message and I somehow have the feeling, the link which gets generated doesn't fit to my GitLab server.

```
Error: Failed to install 'unknown package' from GitLab:
  cannot open URL 'https://gitlab.rlp.net/api/v4/projects/madejung%2FMQqueue.git/repository/files/DESCRIPTION/raw?ref=master'
```

My complete code to test at the moment is

```
creds <- git2r::cred_ssh_key(publickey="~/.ssh/id_rsa_gitlab.pub",
                             privatekey="~/.ssh/id_rsa_gitlab")
devtools::install_git(
  url='git@gitlab.rlp.net:madejung/MQqueue.git',
  quiet=FALSE, 
  credentials=creds)

devtools::install_gitlab(
  repo='madejung/MQqueue.git',
  host='gitlab.rlp.net',
  quiet=FALSE, 
  credentials=creds
)
```

My `id_rsa_gitlab.pub` file looks like this and is just a single line:

```
ssh-rsa AAAA....fiwbw== rsa-key-20200121
```

The `id_rsa_gitlab` file has just the code:

```
AAABA.....3WNSIAGE=
```

### Update

On my Mac system it works as expected after installing the `libssh2` library via `homebrew` and and recompiling `git2r` with `install.packages("git2r", type = "source")`.

So the working code on my machine is:

```
creds <- git2r::cred_ssh_key(publickey="~/.ssh/id_rsa_gitlab.rlp.net.pub",
                             privatekey="~/.ssh/id_rsa_gitlab.rlp.net")
devtools::install_git(
  url='git@gitlab.rlp.net:madejung/MQqueue.git',
  quiet=FALSE, 
  credentials=creds
)
```

For some strange reason, the `devtools::install_git` call needs about a minute to fail in the end. I have no idea where the problem here is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After struggling for almost a day, I found a solution I can live with...

I first created a PAT (Personal Access Token) in my gitlab account and granted full API access. For some reason the read_only access didn't worked and I am now tired to figure out what the problem is.

After this I had still problems to install my package and for some reason, the `wininet` setting for downloading doesn't work.

I used the command `capabilities("libcurl")` to check if `libcurl` is available on my windows, which was and tried to overwrite `wininet` to `libcurl` by using `method='libcurl'` in the install function. Somehow, this was not enough so I overwrote the options variable `download.file.method` directly.

```
options("download.file.method"='libcurl')
devtools::install_gitlab(
  repo='madejung/MQqueue',
  auth_token='Ho...SOMETHING...xugzb',
  host='gitlab.rlp.net',
  quiet=FALSE, force=TRUE
)
```